# Create clickhouse temporary table with doobie

Tags: scala, clickhouse, scala-cats, cats-effect, doobie

I want to create clickhouse temporary table with doobie, but i don't know how to add session_id parameter in query

I tried

```js
val sql =
          sql"CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE " ++ Fragment.const(tableName) ++ sql"( call_id String ) ENGINE Memory()"

HC.setClientInfo("session_id",sessionId.toString) *> sql.update.run
```

but this not working